# VueJS - needs to click the button twice for Copy to Clipboard to work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a text input with a button copy that's in an accordion.

[image]

This is my code on the copy button

```
<accordian>
    <accordian-panel heading="Feed ID">
        <div class="form-row form-row-layout">
              <input type="text" v-model="feed.app_id" id="feedAppId" />
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="copyFeedIdBtn" @click.prevent="copyFeedId()" data-clipboard-target="#feedAppId">Copy</button>
         </div>
    </accordian-panel>
</accordian>
```

This is the method:

```
copyFeedId()
{
     this.clipboard = new Clipboard(jQuery('#copyFeedIdBtn')[0],{
        container: this.$el
     });
                
      this.clipboard.on('success', (e) => {
             this.$appToasts.success('Feed ID copied to clipboard');
             e.clearSelection();
      });

      this.clipboard.on('error', (e) => {
            console.error('Action:', e.action);
            console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
      });
 }
```

I noticed that I had to clicked the button twice in order for this to work.

I think the reason why it isn't working because when the accordion is closed, the  `<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="copyFeedIdBtn" @click.prevent="copyFeedId()" data-clipboard-target="#feedAppId">Copy</button>` isnt registered yet. I'm not yet sure how to register the event even if the accordion is still closed. I noticed that when I try to run the `jQuery('#copyFeedIdBtn')[0]` and it returned `undefined` when it's still closed, but when it is open, there's a data in it already.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Unless someone knows exactly what you are using, it is hard for us to help you, can you please create a CodePen to illustrate the issue? So we also know the packages and versions you are using...

Comment: why are you using jQuery if you have vue?

Comment: As i understand you your issue is calling on a not existend dom object, by invoking the handler. Use `await vm.$nextTick()` to wait for a render. Or use vue.

Comment: Hi @Estradiaz - how can i use that? Sorry, i'm pretty noob about this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```js
      copyFeedId()
      {
        const el = getElementById('feedAppId');
        el.focus();
        el.setSelectionRange(0, el.value.length);
        try
        {
          const result = document.execCommand('copy');
          if (result)
          {
            // success;
          }
          else
          {
            // failure
            console.log('Could not copy to clipboard');
          }
        }
        catch (e)
        {
          // error
          console.log(e.message || e);
        }
      }
```